# Does deleting an email contact delete the previous emails from that contact?

Tags: gmail

I have two contacts that changed their emails.  In order to have the correct email address auto pop, I deleted the first contact, but before deleting the second, I wondered if, once deleted, does that delete all previous emails from that contact?

Comment: Why not "edit" the contact, rather than "delete" and "new"?

Answer (score 5):

## Short answer

In Gmail, deleting a contact from the contact manager doesn't delete the messages received from that contact.

## Explanation

Contacts are stored in a separate area from messages.

## Bonus

You can access the Google Contact manager from the Gmail web UI but also from https://contacts.google.com.